# Unconfirmed transaction for 18 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

My transaction has been sitting in mempool unconfirmed for 18 days. I was dumb enough to use a custody wallet so there's absolutely nothing I can do to fix it on my end. Is there anything I can do to get it kicked off the blockchain?